# Tis the Season hat short description is confusing/inconsistent

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash-2012

The short description for [Tis the Season](http://winterba.sh/tis-the-season) (on the main [winterba.sh](http://winterba.sh/) page) is "post or vote during Christmas".  I'd expect "during Christmas" to cover the whole holiday season or possibly the twelve days of [Christmastide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmastide), as per [this english.stackexchange question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44806/what-preposition-should-i-use-before-christmas).  It's also inconsistent with the New Year's Eve and L'chaim hats, which use the preposition "on" instead of "during".

Could the short description be changed to "post or vote on Christmas Day"?

Comment: "Christmas" for me is the 24th, so yeah, a specific date would be bloody wonderful.

Comment: Technically, depending on where you are timezone-wise, it's Christmas Day UTC, so for me (I'm UTC-5) that's 24 December 2012 at 19:00 CST.

Comment: And I've just gained it on Robotics... 2012-12-**24** 12:20UTC ???

Comment: @Aarthi, it does not only depend on the timezone, but also on culture. In Germany, the most important Christmas day is the 24th. In the evening Santa will visit families (either in person or in secret while the children are at church/christmas market). In the USA, however, children will not get presents until the morning of the 25th because Santa visits at night.

Comment: @Andrew - all time sensitive hats are for a 48 hour period. The day +/- 12 hours. So "Christmas" starts 12 noon on the 24th and ends 12 noon on the 26th - UTC times of course.

Comment: @ChrisF I was wondering if that was the case... Season's Greetings to all in any case :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ChrisF basically got it in the comments: to compensate for time zones, we added twelve hours to the window of opportunity, meaning "Christmas" actually *does* span through two days, or both the 24th *and* the 25th. From this perspective, the description is accurate -- Christmas's duration is multiple days (Eve and Day) as is the window of opportunity in which to earn the hat.

Comment: So we're learning for next year ;-)

Answer (score 5):

When you actually click the hat it says "Post or vote on December 25", so that should probably be the general description as well.

On another note, I got this hat today (which is the 24th in Norway) – maybe the Winter Bash actually have taken into account the different Christmas Days in the various countries/time zones, and that's the reason for the vague description?

I do agree though, a more precise short description is definitely preferred.

Comment: [This is deliberate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159577/off-by-twelve-error-and-i-feel-fine-hat#comment462135_159579)