# Why are date-based hats awarded too early?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash

I just got the [And I Feel Fine](http://winterba.sh/and-i-feel-fine) hat which states "post or vote on December 21".

Does SE have a time machine now?

Comment: I just earned this hat now. :)

Comment: While it's 21st December somewhere, it's definitely not 21st December UTC.

Comment: I think it's an off by 12 hours error. It's just gone noon here in the UK

Comment: This is going to be a fairly highly upvoted question as all you have to do to get the hat is upvote it!

Comment: so really do have a time machine ... i have got too

Comment: Probably trying to do as much as possible before the end of the world tomorrow! ;)

Comment: @Sha Wiz Dow Ard today*  :p

Comment: @Travis oh my! <going to buy some water>

Comment: Who cares, can't be a bug if it gives you more hats

Comment: Amazing how everyone are now wearing it, as if fearing it will disappear!

Comment: Thanks to that hat, now the Beatles song is stuck on my head.

Comment: FWIW, each day exists somewhere on Earth for a whole 50 hours. (Dec 21 2012 starts in time zone UTC+14 at 10:00 UTC Dec 20 and ends in time zone UTC−12 at 12:00 UTC Dec 22).

Comment: This is probably preemptive, since they wont be able to actually give it out after the world explodes.

Comment: It is a play around the number 12: Change position to the digits of 12, and you get 21; the hat has been awarded 12 hours before the time...

Comment: Me too... back to the future my dear friends

Comment: Lol, [tweeted about it](https://twitter.com/jpluimers/status/281773599461879810) before finding this question

Comment: You know, I was going to post this, but I figured it was some variant on the pluralization errors.

Comment: @bfavaretto wat. Beatles? Not R.E.M.?

Comment: Why not use the timezone of the user's browser?

Comment: @finnw because the hat is awarded server side, and there's no reliable way for the server to know the client's local  time.

Comment: I find the question/answer owners here rather humorous - it appears was asked by an employee and answered by a non-employee, but in reality the roles were reversed when asked.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

So, the official answer is: we over-awarded the hat so that people in Auckland / Tokyo / Shanghai / Vanuatu wouldn't have to wait until *their* midday to receive it.

You're all mostly programmers, so you should be reasonably familiar with how much of a headache timezones can be sometimes. Since Stack Exchange is run on UTC, we have to leave a +14/-12 hour buffer so that the nations around the International Date Line have just as much opportunity to grab hats as people along the 0 longitude.

This behavior **will also occur** for the other hats that are date-sensitive. This included L'Chaim, and will include Tis the Season and the New Year's Eve Hat / Auld Lang Syne.

Basically: *Don't panic!* It's a feature, not a bug!

Comment: Phew... I can feel the panic leaving my body ;)

Comment: "You're all mostly programmers" - No need for insults.

Comment: @Yannis ***YANNIS***.

Comment: Cheers, but don't forget the towel!

Comment: Yeah, calling @Yannis a programmer. Bundling the rest of us with the likes of him.

Comment: @Oded to be fair, I called him "mostly" a programmer.

Comment: @Oded if you accept this answer, then Gamecat gets the pirate hat. Help a fellow meta-er out. :P

Comment: Hehe... this being the official story (um. answer)... Not a problem. Just as soon as I get my "Buddy Breathing" :)

Comment: @Oded yay he got it!

Comment: Always happy to help out a fellow Meta-er... even if he isn't wearing any hat ;)

Comment: Wait... That means that I **should have** gotten the LChaim hat as I did post/vote on the morning of December 17th EST. No? @Aarthi

Comment: Hmm, we may not have had the extended window for L'Chaim. I shall ask. @amanaplan

Comment: @Aarthi kk let me know if there is a conclusion ^_^

Answer (score 65):

When tomorrow is today, either time has ended, or we are too bored to care about dates.

Yup this post gave me the hat too. Feature confirmed.

Comment: My head asplode

Comment: Seeing as the SO timemachine posted from the 21st, I think we will survive.

Comment: It is already Dec 21 in the Pacific Ocean.

Comment: @nhahtdh - but Stack Exchange usually operates on UTC and it's not 21/12 here.

Comment: @ChrisF: Just offer the most logical explanation that I can think of, that doesn't make this a bug.

Comment: @ChrisF - not this time, we're intentionally +/-12hr with the hats on time ranges since over-awarding is better than feeling left out, festive!

Comment: @NickCraver - fair enough. I can't complain.

Comment: Nice hat trick.

Comment: @NickCraver i love this hat thing ... it was totally unexpected

Comment: @Nick you are not over-awarding enough! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B14

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes - I had very little to do with the hats...I just stumble around our code and read it (sometimes), before making crazy changes.

Comment: @NickCraver You should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 18):

Nah, The Mayans weren't prepared for the confuddling time zones. So hopefully the end of the world will be delayed by a few millenia while they are mired in bureaucracy trying to untangle tricky issues like:

- Should the end of the world be phased in over a 24 hour period to
  ensure doom happens on the correct day for everyone.
- How should leap seconds and the move to Gregorian calendar be accommodated?
- Should the next stone calendar be carved using a Stardate datum?
- How to deal with pesky loose ends like time dilation

Comment: And don't forget daylight saving time.

Answer (score 12):

As per [current time zone](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/) it is 21st December [in Auckland](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=22). So the description of this hat is correct.

Comment: "*So the description of this hat is correct.*".. in Auckland.

Comment: So it is friday in Auckland...

Comment: UTC (GMT/Zulu)-time: Thursday, December 20, 2012  The Mayan Calendar finishes one of its great circles in December 2012. Some believe this is a sign of the End of the World.

**In Auckland this happens on Saturday, December 22, 2012 at 12:11:00 AM.**

Answer (score 6):

StackOverflow is preparing for the [DOOMSDAY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_phenomenon), so distributing the hats right away before we face a scary day tommorow...Chill out guys users with maya hat are safe ~Cheers~

Answer (score 3):

This is a live post from India and it's almost 21st December 2012 and no harm till now.

Comment: Well, it should happen "during the day" so we'll have to sit and wait. :-D

Comment: The Maya's lived in South America, so we probably have to wait a couple of hours.

Comment: it doesn't matter if its happen or not but i believe in living like there's not tomorrow...

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be 12 hours out from UTC. SO does run on UTC doesn't it? Funny, I got the hat on SO but not on Meta.

Comment: You just earned it on meta too. Needed to wait [because ..........](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159196/how-much-time-does-it-take-to-award-any-hat/159209#comment461034_159198)

Comment: @hims056 Ah. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This effect also occurs with regards to the winterbash-2013 hats.

[image]
[image] 
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

And they continued to peck away at their keyboards, unaware of hats with power beyond their comprehension were already being set in motion....

Answer (score 1):

They're just hedging their bets. If the world really *does* end tomorrow, we won't get those badges. *Status-as-designed.*

Answer (score 0):

20/12 here and I got my hat. We must be, *ahem*, Out of Time.