# Received December 25th hat on December 24th!

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Off by twelve error? — “And I Feel Fine” hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159577/off-by-twelve-error-and-i-feel-fine-hat)

I received the [Tis the season](http://winterba.sh/tis-the-season) hat a few minutes ago, even though the description says it is for posting or voting on December 25th. It is December 24th, as of now.

[image]

I was under the impression that SO follows UTC time, according to which it would be afternoon on the 24th right now.

Comment: It's 25 december in New Zealand. Why shouldn't they receive the hat?

Comment: There is a *wide* margin to avoid tears^h^h^h^h complaints from those who missed that hat due to time zone differences.

Comment: @Chichiray But doesn't SO follow UTC time?

Comment: For posts, yes. Locale-specific timezone is not so relevant on posts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), similarly to [the apocalyptic hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159748/162704):

> So, the official answer is: we over-awarded the hat so that people in Auckland / Tokyo / Shanghai / Vanuatu wouldn't have to wait until their midday to receive it.
>
> ...
>
> This behavior will also occur for the other hats that are date-sensitive. This included L'Chaim, and will include Tis the Season and the New Year's Eve Hat / Auld Lang Syne.
>
> Basically: Don't panic! It's a feature, not a bug!

Comment: Alright. Thank you. Will accept in 11 minutes.

Comment: `Dont panic!` .. :D

Comment: Don't know which of the contrasts are least surprising.