# Winter Is Coming?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2013

I just got awarded the "Winter Is Coming" hat - it's still the 19th? The hat is for the 20th!

[image]

What is going on?

Comment: You should get the *Link to the future* hat for that (if there is one).

Comment: Small tip from own experience: always save screenshots in `.png` format and not `.jpg` and you'll have much better quality. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Oh, it's already December 20th 02:27 AM [in Kiritimati](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=274).

> [image]

And as stated [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159577/off-by-twelve-error-and-i-feel-fine-hat/159748#159748):

> we over-awarded the hat so that people in Auckland / Tokyo / Shanghai / Vanuatu wouldn't have to wait until their midday to receive it.

...and later on:

> This behavior will also occur for the other hats that are date-sensitive

This was in Winter Bash 2012 but can't see any reason to change the behavior in 2013. :)

Comment: Wow. some people are in the future

Comment: I was just looking this up...but shouldn't everything be UTC?

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby posts yes but hats no. Will look up old official statement.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159748/161198 @ShadowWizard