# How come the year doesn't show here?

Tags: support, dates

Not sure if this question belongs here, but why doesn't the year for the June dates show up on this page? https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/3109/sheriff

[image]

Comment: Dude, it's February.

Comment: I find this incredibly irritating; several times I've been fooled by "feb 12". I think its February 2012 but its actually the 12th of February.

Comment: Related; [show-the-whole-date-even-for-questions-within-the-last-12-months](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226428/show-the-whole-date-even-for-questions-within-the-last-12-months)

Comment: i now am going to delete the duplicate question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those dates are less than a year ago; come June 2014 they'll earn their `'13`.

Until then they are considered recent enough that you don't need to be reminded in what year they fell, since those dates are *always* in the past.

To be precise, the year is hidden until the date is at least [360 days in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1306/add-year-to-question-and-answer-dates/1307#comment8301_2470).

Comment: @Downvoter - Why do you think this is incorrect? June 2014 isn't here yet, so the implication is that it is referring to the only possible June (2013). This answer seems pretty spot on to me.

Comment: [Questions and answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212600/winter-is-coming) (random example) show the year no matter what if it's not the *current* year. This appears to be an inconsistency in the display of dates.

Comment: @animuson: it could be that the 'no year until 360 days in the past' rule was rescinded but the devs missed the badge pages..

Comment: This mechanism can also be seen in the list of favorites, bounties, and questions in a profile.

Comment: Just for posterity: Jeff's comment is from July 2009, and like you said things seem different on different parts of the site. For posts, [years are indeed shown if the calendar year is not the current year](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171291/please-add-year-to-dates-in-previous-year/171295#171295). Today, [the last December 2013 question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214493/any-other-reputation-bonus-except-association) shows "asked Dec 31 '13 at 23:02". I assume it did the same on January 1st.