# Is there something wrong with "Mmmm Bacon" hat mechanism?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

Today while searching I voted on a question and suddenly got a hat so out of curiosity I checked it and it said I received a "Mmmm Bacon" hat, as shown below.

[image: Screen Shot]

Now the question is how a hat that is to be awarded on 30th of December is awarded on 29th of December? Is this a bug or something else that I failed to understand?

Comment: +1 I have received this hat just now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No – it's December 30th already on some Pacific islands, therefore you get the hat now already. See the following question for the general motivation:

[Why are date-based hats awarded too early?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159577/why-are-date-based-hats-awarded-too-early/159748#159748)

See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288738/295232) for the exact award times for the December 25th hat (Bûche de Noël) – you can extrapolate for the Mmmm Bacon hat.

<sub>(copied from my answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/340492/4751173))</sub>

Comment: If you say that they have kept 12 hours of gap due to time zone the even at the time of this comment it is till not even 11:58 UTC. Then how can i have the hat earlier then 12 hours????

Comment: I never said 12 hours; it's actually *14* hours 'before' and *12* hours 'after'. The world's timezones range from UTC+14 to UTC-12.

Comment: Actually It is there in the answer you suggested in the first link. And why 14 hours before(just out of curiosity don't know the logic for 14 hours before)??

Comment: The `+/-` in that answer was probably meant as `±` which means **about, but not exactly**. I explained why it is 14 hours in my previous comment.

Comment: Please link to http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245122/115866 when answering questions like this, that's the canonical post. Thanks!