# Who shared my question or answer?

Tags: support, questions, answers

Can I know who shared my answers or questions in other posts, or this is not possible?

Sometimes some member answers, and in the answer shares a old question or answer for more clarification. Can I find such cases?

Comment: You mean within the SE network of sites, right?

Comment: I mean in SE network @rene

Comment: I completely understand why you'd like to know. I also know that once you post a message on any public message board for any reason, it's out there. You might technically 'own' your writing, but there's is no one who can defend you. I am a photographer who found my image used by someone without my permission. It broke copyright. Big deal. I can do nothing because I don't sell my images and it wasn't used commercially.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could [find the posts sharing a link to your post](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/609690/find-posts-linking-to-c-nre-canonical) by searching SEDE for the question (or answer) link of your post.

```
select top 10 *
from   posts
where  body like '%stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142%'
or     body like '%stackoverflow.com/q/4660142%'
```

That query is a common question about a `NullReferenceException`, which I think is the most used canonical in the C# tag. You can change it for your own questions or answers, but it will be quite a process to go over all of them.

Rene does have an even better suggestion: use [the `PostLinks` table](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/609691), which already does most of the heavy lifting.

Comment: Maybe PostLinks can help there: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/609691

Comment: Oh yes. Totally missed that one. Updated!

Comment: Just to be pedantic, though, note that these queries tell you *where* the links are, not *who* shared them, which is very difficult to know for sure. That said, on average, the original author of the post that contains the link is *most likely* to be the person who put it there. Also, links from chat rooms and other sites, of course, are not possible to track on our end without seeing the actual links (the /q/postid/userid URLs from the "share" link). But yeah PostLinks is as close as you can get and covers most of it.

Comment: Thank you @PatrickHofman this should help me

Answer (score 5):

Well, of course there is the Linked Questions list. For example, when I link to [a random question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288987/is-there-something-wrong-with-mmmm-bacon-hat-mechanism), you will see this question popping up in the Linked Questions list of that question.

[image]

But that only works for *questions*.

Sometimes, it's possible to determine this from the shared URL. Here is the link when I click the `share` link under your question:

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289004/295232
```

The `295232` is my user ID on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel).

However, if I just copy the URL from my browser's address bar, it's not possible:

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289004/who-share-my-question-or-answer
```

This link just contains the question ID but no reference to my user.

Without a URL, you **cannot** determine who shares links to your posts. If they're successful, and you have an idea who did it, you might be able to see it via the [Announcer badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/74/announcer?userid=295232), but that's a rare case.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. What has the share url and your user id to do with if a post of yours is linked to from another post? Or I read something else in the question.

Comment: @Glorfindel some times some member answer and in the answer share a old question or answer for more clarification, so this is what i mean !

Comment: @rene It's relevant because if the use the `share` url, the sharer's user ID is included in the url, and is tracked by SE whenever that link is followed, so you *can* in fact determine who has shared your post and how many people have followed it, but if they share it without using SE's "share" link, then you can't.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't immediately clear to me that it's about sharing *within* the SE network. So my answer is everything but spot-on, but I'll leave it this way because it complements Patrick's one.